# Improving the performance of selects and inserts of latest records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table in which I have a column known as `BatchId`. I want to make sure that select and insert on that table are very fast, when the batchId to be inserted is new and to be selected is the latest.

```
Select * 
from table 
where batchId = @maximumBatchId
```

I don't care about the performance of other batchIds.

Adding index on `batchId` does improve the performance but over the time when index size increases, it may not be the same.

Comment: If you are getting a seek then size shouldn't have any drastic type of impact on the performance (the more important things are how many rows are scanned by the seek, how many lookups are performed, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
order by batchid desc;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(batchid desc)`.

If multiple rows could have the same `batchid`, then use:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
```

Comment: I was also wondering if desc index would do the trick, but wasn't sure as could not find any article saying it.

Comment: @Deepak In most cases an index can be useful for the start or the end (e.g. it can start at either end and scan in either direction). Some info [here](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/02/so-is-it-a-seek-or-a-scan.html)